# Ionic 3 Component, Runtime error: Cannot read property "push" of undefined (nav)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I created a sidebar component for my Ionic 3 App. I wanted to have dynamically-populated buttons on it, to push different pages. However no matter what I do, when I click on one of the buttons from the sidebar, Ionic gives an error that says: "Runtime error: Cannot read property "push" of undefined". 
I'm importing Nav, but when I console.log(this.nav), it is undefined. I've been on this for literally days. Please help me...

**sidebar.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-button *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)"> {{p.title}}<ion-icon class="icon" name="{{p.icon}}"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**sidebar.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HomePage } from '../../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/login/login'

@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar',
  templateUrl: 'sidebar.html'
})
export class SidebarComponent {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav;

  pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any, icon: any }>;

  pages = [
    {title:'Dashboard', component: HomePage, icon:'home'}
  ];

  constructor() {

  }

  openPage(page) {
    this.nav.push(LoginPage);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use NavController and not Nav for what you are trying to accomplish and you also need to inject it into constructor to make this work see below:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HomePage } from '../../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/login/login'

@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar',
  templateUrl: 'sidebar.html'
})
export class SidebarComponent {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav;

  pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any, icon: any }>;

  pages = [
    {title:'Dashboard', component: HomePage, icon:'home'}
  ];

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  openPage(page) {
    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
  }

}
```

Thoroughly check this documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your pages declaration inside of your constructor instead.

> **In your sidebar.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HomePage } from '../../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/login/login'

@Component({
selector: 'sidebar',
templateUrl: 'sidebar.html'
})
export class SidebarComponent {
@ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav;

pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any, icon: any }>;

constructor() {

this.pages = [
{title:'Dashboard', component: HomePage, icon:'home'}
];

}

openPage(page) {
this.nav.push(LoginPage);
}

}
```

Also, unless you want to have stacked pages, I recommend that you use nav.setRoot() instead.